# Lenovo E530 Enter Bios over VGA

Tags: bios, vga, thinkpad

My ~3yr old Lenovo Thinkpad E530 starts to fall apart (literally!) but I wont give up without fighting. As the case is broken (almost the whole corner is "missing") it didn't take long and now the cable that connects the pc with the screen is more or less broken. Over an external screen I can still use the pc but I can't get the BIOS to display on the external screen (connected over VGA). Any ideas? (and yes, BIOS and not UEFI!) So far I've been able to get into the BIOS (by pressing some F-keys I got this awful sound) but then pressing F6 (the dedicated button for connections to external screens) does absolutely nothing.

I want to configure the pc to automatically display everything over VGA. I guess changing some BIOS settings will be necessary?!